# What is the grammatical explanation of "sí" in "entre sí"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

This means "they" mix together (or each other):

> mezclan **entre sí**

In my knowledge, **sí** is to acknowledge or affirm. Please explain the effect or function of sí in this case. Does it create "mutual" relations among the words or objects?

When I want to say "gravity pulls the planets among them", can I say something like 'las planetas se sacalan entre sí'?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"[Sí](https://dle.rae.es/s%C3%AD)" is also the reflexive form of the third person pronouns (*él, ella, ellos, ellas*), which must always be preceded by a preposition. This "sí" is completely unrelated (has different etymology) to the word "sí" meaning "yes".

*Reflexive* means that the subject applies an action to themselves. A possible translation in some cases would be "*preposition*+himself/herself/themselves". The word "mismo/misma" is often appended to emphasize the reflexiveness of the action, but it is not mandatory. For example:

- Dijo para sí (mismo)... / *He said to himself...*
- Lo alejó de sí (misma) / *She pushed him away from her(self)*
- El frío en sí no me molesta: me molesta no poder ir a la piscina (*The cold weather itself does not bother me: what bothers me is not being able to go to the pool*)

The construction "entre sí" means therefore "among themselves", which might more naturally be translated as "each other" or "together" in some cases:

- Los planetas se atraen entre sí (*The planets attract each other*)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is *si* as the third person reflexive pronoun both singular and plural. It also work for *Usted(es)*.

I would have said that a translation might be they (or you plural polite form) mix amongst themselves (or yourselves) but more context might help to clarify.